# Does DataFrame.loc not iterate over each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I was expecting this code to print "new string" between each row in my dataframe...

```
def isASCII(input_string):
    print(input_string)
    if isinstance(input_string, str):
        orig_length = len(input_string)
        print('new String!')
        listThing = [letter for letter in input_string if ord(letter) < 127]
        print(listThing)
        new_length = len(listThing)
        return (orig_length == new_length)
    else: 
        return False

#isASCII('test') true
#isASCII('一些文字') false
#isASCII('sometext字') false
english_ga = dupe_free_ga.loc[isASCII(dupe_free_ga['App'].to_string())]
```

Instead 'new string!' appears once. Am I just not understanding how loc works here?

Comment: `loc` does some magic behind the scenes, but at its core it's still an ordinary Python object and has to obey Python calling conventions. You call `isASCII` once and don't use any looping constructs, so `isASCII` is only going to be called once. That's not up to `loc` to decide.

Comment: What I was looking for, I believe, was dataframe.apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to split this line

```
english_ga = dupe_free_ga.loc[isASCII(dupe_free_ga['App'].to_string())]
```

to illustrate how Python evaluates it:

```
tmp = isASCII(dupe_free_ga['App'].to_string())
english_ga = dupe_free_ga.loc[tmp]
```

So, what would you expect `dupe_free_ga.loc[True]` or `dupe_free_ga.loc[False]` to return? Isn't that exactly what you get there?

Comment: I think the source of my confusion was seeing examples where you could do things like df.loc[df['Nanme'].str.contains('test')]